# Creating a SQL "parameterized" query or view in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's a view with a hard-coded equality:

```
create or replace view v1 as select * from mytable where x=3;
```

Is it possible create a "parameterized" equivalent of this in Postgresql?

```
create or replace SOMETHING v2(value) as
  select * from mytable where x=value;
```

(Update: We have good answers for Postgresql here, and none for the other databases, so I'm amending the question to be Posgtresql-specific.)

Comment: 1) `create or replace view v1 as select * from mytable` then `select * from view where x=3` 2) Not a view but [Prepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) and [Execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgresql version

```
create or replace function v2(val int)
returns setof mytable language sql as $$
    select *
    from mytable
    where x = val;
$$;

select * from v2(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is very product dependent, but for postgres you can use functions, but views work the same way, so there are not really any need to do it

and you can use materialized views as well https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html

```
CREATE tABLe mytable ( f1 int, f2 int, x int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE FUNCTION v2(int) RETURNS TABLE(f1 int, f2 text)
    AS $$ select f1,f2 from mytable where x=$1; $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM v2(42);
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

| f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
CREATE VIEW myview As select f1,f2,x from mytable
```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW
> ```

```
SELECT f1,f2 FROM myview WHERE x = 42
```

| f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uxqbRUSr)

Answer (score -1):

I'll respond to the subject line of the question and suggest that you've answered your own question. A view is just a query, so you "parameterize" it the same way you would any other query--with a where statement.

In the same way you would write:

```
select a, b, c
from table1
where a=5;
```

you can write:

```
select a, b, c
from view1
where a=5;
```

Suppose view one is defined as:

```
create view1 as
   select *
   from table1;
```

then the second query above is as if you wrote:

```
select a, b, c
from (
    select *
    from table1
) as s  -- s for subquery, since postgres requires one to name this
where a=5;
```

As you can see, these are all functionally equivalent.

I hope this helps. If, on the other hand, you really are looking for a mechanism to create views, then as the other answers suggest, you'll want to use a procedural language.